# Porque no me ha actualiza el campo estado?

Tags: sql-server

```
create table profesor(
idProfesor int,
nombre varchar (20),
constraint pk_idProfesor primary key (idProfesor)
)

create table estudiante(
idEstudiante int,
nombre varchar (20),
constraint pk_idEstudiante primary key (idEstudiante)
)

create table materia(
idMateria int,
nombre varchar (20),
estado varchar (20)
constraint pk_idMateria primary key (idMateria)
)

create table materiaProfesor(
aula int,
fecha date,
idProfesor1 int,
idEstudiante1 int,
idMateria1 int,
CONSTRAINT fk_idProfesor1 FOREIGN KEY (idProfesor1) REFERENCES Profesor (idProfesor),
CONSTRAINT fk_idMateria1 FOREIGN KEY (idMateria1) REFERENCES materia (idMateria),
)

update materia
set estado = 'Aprobado'
from materia 
inner join estudiante on materia.idMateria = estudiante.idEstudiante
where estudiante.nombre = 'Pedro'
```

Answer (score 1):

Claramente estas indicando, en el `inner join`, una relación inexistente. IdEstudiante no es igual a IdMateria

```
inner join estudiante on materia.idMateria = estudiante.idEstudiante
```

Siguiendo el modelo que expones la sentencia debería ser:

```
update materia
set estado = 'Aprobado'
from materia 
inner join materiaProfesor on materia.idMateria = materiaProfesor.idMateria1
inner join estudiante on materiaProfesor.idEstudiante1 = estudiante.idEstudiante
where estudiante.nombre = 'Pedro'
```